# Flutter - Get auto time information with iPhone

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, config, auto

I am working on a project with Flutter and I need to know if the mobile device has automatic time configured. exactly the same as thishttps://pub.dev/packages/datetime_setting but with iPhone

Could you guide me to obtain information on the automatic time setting with iPhone?